# python, how to call instance's attribute in decorator

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-decorators

How to call instance attribute in decorator in decorator. The following are my test codes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8

class Foo(object):
    """"""
    def __init__(self):
        """"""
        self.a = 1

    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kw):
            """"""
            print self.a # or do something with self.a
            self.a += 1
        return wrapper

    @decorator
    def call_decorator(self):
        """"""
        pass
```

and

```
In [1]: import foo

In [2]: f = foo.Foo()

In [3]: f.call_decorator
Out[3]: <bound method Foo.wrapper of <foo.Foo object at 0x7fcc72c6a710>>

In [4]: f.call_decorator()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-70d92b784c01> in <module>()
----> 1 f.call_decorator()

/home/fit/log/1228/foo.py in wrapper(*args, **kw)
     11         def wrapper(*args, **kw):
     12             """"""
---> 13             print self.a
     14         return wrapper
     15 

NameError: global name 'self' is not defined

In [5]:
```

And if I add `self` in `def decorator(self, func):`, and error will occur in `@decorator`, it needs 2 arguments. Decorator is not easy to understand.

So, I just want to use the attribute `a` of instance `f` in the decorator, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's `wrapper` who receives `self` among any other function's arguments, not `decorator`, so the definition should be like:

```
def decorator(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)  # a good thing to do
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kw):
        print self.a # or do something with self.a
        self.a += 1
        # if you need to call it, otherwise what's the point of the decorator:
        return func(self, *args, **kw)  
    return wrapper
```