# How access to 'self' attribut in decorator function added dynamically to an instance

Tags: python, class, instance, decorator, python-decorators

My goal is to be able to adding decorator dynamically to all method of class, before and after instantiation.

I need to use self inner my decoractor added after class is instanciate in variable.

It is working  when I add decoractor to class method  directly

but not for instantiate class method.

In my example, I have 2 test class, one wrapper `apply_trigger`, which apply the `active_trigger` wrapper to all methods of class or instantiate class :

```py
 def active_trigger(func):
     @wraps(func)
     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
         def afterexec(obj: object, func,*args, **kwargs):
             a = func(obj,*args, **kwargs)
             # process on obj => SELF
             print(obj)
             return a
         return afterexec(args[0], func, *args[1:], **kwargs)
     return wrapper

def apply_trigger(cls):

    for name, m in inspect.getmembers(cls, lambda x: inspect.isfunction(x) or inspect.ismethod(x)):
        setattr(cls , name, active_trigger(m))
    return cls


class test1():
    def method_test1(self, a:int):
        print(self)
        print(a)

@apply_trigger
class test2():
    

    def method_test2(self,b:int, *args, **kwargs):
        print(b)

    def method_t2ex(self,b:int):
        print(b,'_EXEC_')
```

I need  to add decorator to all methods dynamically .
In the case of test2, it is working

```py
t2 = test2()
t2.method_test2(2)
```

but in the case of decorator added after instanciation, there are no 'self' pass in the decorator `active_trigger`

```py
t1 = apply_trigger(test1())
t1.method_test1(11)
```

My debugger show at the wrapper step `wrapper(*args, **kwargs)` :

for the test2 case. `args` : `(<__main__.test2 object at 0x7feae10bdf90>,2)`

for the test1 case. `args` : `(11)`

How get the `self` attribut in test1 while decorator execution ?

---

### UPDATE

Thanks to the explanation of @juanpa.arrivillaga

I had find a way to make with 2 distinct decorator when I have a class or an instance.

I use a decorator with parameter  in the case of instance, where I pass the instance as parameter.

```py
 def active_trigger(func):
     @wraps(func)
     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
         def afterexec(obj: object, func,*args, **kwargs):
             a = func(obj,*args, **kwargs)
             # process on obj => SELF
             print(obj)
             return a
         return afterexec(args[0], func, *args[1:], **kwargs)
     return wrapper

def active_trigger_instance(self):
    def active_trigger(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            def afterexec(func,*args, **kwargs):
                a = func(*args, **kwargs)
                print(self)
                return a
            return afterexec(func, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return active_trigger

def apply_trigger(cls):

    import inspect
    if inspect.isclass(cls):
        for name, m in inspect.getmembers(cls, lambda x: inspect.isfunction(x) or inspect.ismethod(x)):
            setattr(cls , name, active_trigger(m))
    else:
        for name, m in inspect.getmembers(type(cls), lambda x: inspect.isfunction(x) or inspect.ismethod(x)):
            setattr(cls , name, active_trigger_instance(cls)(getattr(cls, name)))
    return cls
```

now it is working but maybe there a more elegant way to make it

Comment: You are fundamentally confused. Those are not "class methods". Those are *instance methods*. All methods belong to a *class*. When you adding a function to an attribute of an instance, **that is not a method** and `sekf` will not automatically get passed to it.

Comment: it is working well when you put decorator manually with @ in the class definition  as you could see there : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35099995/python-how-to-call-instances-attribute-in-decorator

Comment: what I mean by class method is before instantiation, if I make the distinction is because in my case the behavior of the two case is distinct, I have edited my post on the purpose, I hope it is more clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, a method is simply *a function that lives in the class namespace*, that when called on an instance, *receives the instance it is called on as the first positional argument*

In other words,

```
some_instance.some_method(arg, x=11)
```

Is roughly equivalent to:

```
type(some_instance).some_method(some_instance, arg, x=11)
```

For the above magic<sup>1</sup> to work then `some_method` must *exist in the class namespace* (or in the namespace of a class in the method resolution order -- that is *inheritance*).

It doesn't matter where the function is *defined*, it matters *in what namespace it is in*:

```
>>> class MyClass:
...     pass
...
>>> my_instance = MyClass()
>>>
>>> def a_method(self):
...     return 42
...
>>> MyClass.a_method = a_method
>>>
>>> my_instance.a_method()
42
```

Note the namespaces:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(MyClass.__dict__)
mappingproxy({'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'MyClass' objects>,
              '__doc__': None,
              '__module__': '__main__',
              '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'MyClass' objects>,
              'a_method': <function a_method at 0x105a301f0>})
>>> pprint(my_instance.__dict__)
{}
```

Now, the following will demonstrate that the instance will not be passed to the function if the function exists in the instance namespace instead of the class namespace

```
>>> def another_method(self):
...     return 88
...
>>> my_instance.another_method = another_method
>>> my_instance.another_method()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: another_method() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
>>>
```

And note the namespaces again:

```
>>> pprint(MyClass.__dict__)
mappingproxy({'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'MyClass' objects>,
              '__doc__': None,
              '__module__': '__main__',
              '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'MyClass' objects>,
              'a_method': <function a_method at 0x105a301f0>})
>>> pprint(my_instance.__dict__)
{'another_method': <function another_method at 0x105a30280>}
```

The above is essentially what you are doing when you do:

```
t1 = apply_trigger(test1())
```

Just that `*args, **kwargs` in your `def wrapper` definition is preventing a `TypeError`.

Now, if you want to do this on an instance, my first suggestions is simply not to, and reconsider your design. But if you really want, you can just create an auxilliary function which does the binding of the first argument *manually* (you could use `functools.partial`),

```
def apply_trigger_to_instance(obj):
    ...
    for name, m in inspect.getmembers(cls, lambda x: inspect.isfunction(x) or inspect.ismethod(x)):    
        bound_m = functools.partial(m, obj)
        setattr(cls , name, active_trigger(m))
```

---

<sup>1</sup> If you want to understand it so it isn't magic, you have to understand the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html)

Comment: Note on "It doesn't matter where the function is defined, it matters in what namespace it is in": While it's not an issue here, the magic that enables no-arg `super()` calls is applied only when the function is on the class by the time the definition of the class completes. Similarly, the name-mangling magic for private variables (ones beginning with `__` and not ending with `__`) depends on being defined within the class. These aren't common cases, but they do matter sometimes (you can perform the magic yourself, but it's annoying for private variable name-mangling, and hard for `super()`).

Comment: Am I missing something, or is this not actually answering the question? I know what the OP is doing wrong, but even so it's hard to see that in the answer, and there is no suggestion for a fix (mind you, a fix would be a royal hack job; this is a terrible thing to do, but it seems like it should either attempt to provide the hack job or clearly explain why it's a terrible idea).

Comment: @ShadowRanger sure, I'm talking specifically about the binding of the instnace

Comment: Yeah, I'm not saying it's wrong for that specific purpose (or even most purposes), but it's not a 100% rule, and someone who is looking at performing monkey-patching of a class or class instance in the first place is likely to run into one of these exceptions eventually.

Comment: my usecase is really specific, I have to do it in this way, because the decorator use a class (with the self process) that use the class instance I need to trigger.
when the decorator is directly on the class I get declaration error .
The only way to resolve it , is to add decorator directly on instance

Comment: @Chrysos "when the decorator is directly on the class I get declaration error " what do you mean by a declaration error?